# If the gcd(s, t)=1, prove $F_s F_t$ divides $F_{st}$ for all s,t > 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> > If the gcd(s, t)=1, prove $F_s F_t$ divides $F_{st}$ for all s,t > 1

$F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence, such that $$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$$

I know that it needs to be shown that $F_s F_t\mid F_{st}$ which has the implication that $F_{st} = F_s F_tk$.

I considered that it may be useful to use the theorem that states: the gcd of two fibonacci numbers is also a Fibonacci number with the form $\gcd(F_s,F_t)= g$ where $g= \gcd(s,t)$ or a Corollary relating to this theorem. But I cannot see how this directly applies to the problem.

Is it valid to say that because a theorem states for any $s>1, t>1$, $F_{st}$ is divisible by $F_s$ then that is an implication for $F_s F_t\mid F_{st}$ because the $\gcd(s,t) =1$?

Comment: Use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_of_Fibonacci_Numbers

Comment: I did mention this Theorem in my original question, but I am confused about how to apply it in this situation. Thanks for your response!

Comment: [Proving that $n|m\implies f_n|f_m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378116/proving-that-nm-implies-f-nf-m)

Answer (score 2):

Using that $\gcd(F_m,F_n) = F_{\gcd(m,n)}$ for all $n,n \in \mathbb{Z_{\gt 2}}$, as you've basically stated and as the link of [GCD of Fibonacci Numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_of_Fibonacci_Numbers) which [lab bhattacharjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441858/if-the-gcds-t-1-prove-f-s-f-t-divides-f-st-for-all-s-t-1#comment7075890_3441858) indicates, you get for $s,t \gt 2$ that

$$\gcd(F_{st},F_{s}) = F_{\gcd(st,s)} = F_{s} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\gcd(F_{st},F_{t}) = F_{\gcd(st,t)} = F_{t} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$\gcd(F_{s},F_{t}) = F_{\gcd(s,t)} = F_{1} = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note \eqref{eq1A} gives that $F_{s} \mid F_{st}$ and \eqref{eq2A} gives that $F_{t} \mid F_{st}$. Since \eqref{eq3A} shows that $F_{s}$ and $F_{t}$ are relatively prime, this means that $F_{s}F_{t} \mid F_{st}$ (e.g., as shown in [if $b$ divides $ck$ and $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime, then $b$ must divides $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870610/if-b-divides-ck-and-b-and-c-are-relatively-prime-then-b-must-divides)).

This just leaves the case where one of $s$ or $t$ is $2$. WLOG, let $s = 2$ so $t$ is odd. Since $F_2 = 1$, the question is asking to prove that $F_{t} \mid F_{2t}$ for all odd $t$. For this, you can use [Proving that $n|m\implies f_n|f_m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378116/proving-that-nm-implies-f-nf-m) that [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967/mathlove)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441858/if-the-gcds-t-1-prove-f-s-f-t-divides-f-st-for-all-s-t-1#comment7075938_3441858) states, since $t \mid 2t$ so $F_t \mid F_{2t}$.